# How can I know what standard Wi-Fi (802.11) I am using in Wi-Fi Direct(Android)?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I realized that when I send bytes using my Wi-Fi Direct-based Android application and I am connected to a Wi-Fi network, my speed reaches a maximum of 67 or 68 Mbps (8 MBps), but if I am not connected to any Wi-Fi network, I simply have the active interface, my speed is close to 220 Mbps (28 MBps).

Why is being connected to a WiFi network reduces my speed on my Wi-Fi Direct link?
How can I know what standard I am using at all times?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will besharing the radio for Wifi network and Wifi direct.
When you disable Wifi network, the radio will be fully used for direct file transfer.